# ajax update panel not working in Facebook iframe

Tags: asp.net, facebook, updatepanel, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a facebook app with an asp.net update panel. It works fine when running outside facebook, however once I run the app in Facebook the update panel stops working. I check the javascript console and found the following errors were occuring.

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message
>   received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this
>   error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(),
>   response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.

Can I use the update panel in my facebook app?

Could this error be from this entry in the web.config file?

```
<add verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" />
```

Answer (score 0):

David,

We'll have to investigate this further. You should be able to use an updatepanel with the Facebook C# SDK (I can't think of a reason why you shouldn't be able to).

Can you provide us a simple example (with html/.aspx and code) that isn't working?

Jay

Comment: I think the problem is with the 4.2.1.0 version of the sdk, because I switched to the 4.1.1.0 version and added the cookieSupported attribute in the web.config file and everything works now. Did not make any other changes to the app.